# Problem using help in Octave

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I cannot get any help information from my octave command prompt. 
Example, when I enter

> octave:1>help rand

I get the error message

> error: fwrite: invalid stream number = -1
>
> error: called from:
>
> error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.3/m/help/**makeinfo**.m at line 147, column 5
>
> error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.3/m/help/help.m at line 62, column 25

Any idea what the problem could be?

[I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and have installed Octave 3.2 using the Ubuntu Software Center]

Comment: Similar error messages for doc command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

short answer: you don't have write permission in the current directory.
At least on my computer the same error is related to a call to 
 mkstemp ("octave_help_XXXXXX", true). Tjis tries to create a temporary file in the current directory and fails.
Try to cd to a writeable directory.

Niko